# How do I make every tile of a tilemap light up

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need every tile of a specific tilemap to have a light/glow effect, but I can't find how to do this on any forums/tutorials...
I don't want to add a light point to every tile which is what I've been doing so far...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [instantiating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) a [particle system](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.html) on each one of the tiles?

Comment: I have no idea what this is or how to do it

Comment: I included links to references talking about both of the topics

Comment: I saw but it's really complicated for me